# How to export parameters from aws parameter store and import into another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssm, amazon-systems-manager, aws-parameter-store

on my **first** aws account I have parameters specified in the following manner:

```
/config/a => value1
/config/b => value2
/config/c/a => value31
/config/c/b => value32
```

I want to move these to my **second** aws account.

I created these parameters in the parameter store manually.

How could I easily copy these values from one account to the other?

Using `aws ssm get-parameters --names "<param-name>"` would be a bit too difficult, since I have way too many parameters.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Retrieve all parameters via `aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path "/relative/path/" --recursive`
2. Write the resulting JSON somewhere down - e.g. into a file
3. Prepare put commands e.g. with JS

```
for (const value of params.Parameters) {
    const { Name, Value } = value;
    console.log(`aws ssm put-parameter --name "${Name}" --value "${Value}" --type "String"`);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I created a utility which does exactly what you want:

```
pip install aws-ssm-copy
aws-ssm-copy --dry-run --source-profile <source> --recursive /
```

Checkout the [aws-ssm-copy](https://pypi.org/project/aws-ssm-copy/) utility and  [blog](https://binx.io/blog/2020/12/21/how-to-copy-aws-ssm-parameters-from-one-account-to-another/) for more details.

Comment: This seems like a great tool but running into error "botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region" even after specifying one with "aws-ssm-copy --dry-run --source-profile dprdnka --source-region us-west-2 --recursive /"

Comment: @metasync just add region=us-west-2 to your profile file

Answer (score 7):

Here is my version that outputs all parameters' `Name`, `Type` and `Value` in a TSV (tab-separated values) format:

```
aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path "/" --recursive --query="Parameters[*].[Name, Type, Value]" --output text
```

Example response:

```
/prod/aaa    String  xxx
/prod/bbb    String  yyy
/prod/ccc    String  zzz
```

Answer (score 5):

May be get-parameters-by-path suits here:
`aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path "/" --recursive`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/get-parameters-by-path.html#synopsis

Answer (score 3):

well I know it is has been a year but, for people who are still trying to figure out here is the detailed solution,

So you need to run following command to fetch all the parameters in your current region:

> `aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path "/" --recursive --with-decryption --region eu-west-2`

you will get a `JSON` formatted response. Just copy the response and paste it into a file (`*.txt` file then rename it to `*.json`). You have your JSON file with all the current parameters

I published that code into a git repository [here](https://github.com/A1M918/aws-ssm-migrate). Just clone that repository after cloning add your desired region here :

```
const ssm = new AWS.SSM({

apiVersion: '2014-11-06';,

region: 'eu-west-2'; // add your destination region here.

});
```

and your `json` file here: `const { Parameters } = await require('<YOUR JSON FILE>.json')`;

Then Install `npm` packages by running command `npm install` and run the script by command `npm start`

Comment: I had to add `--output json` to get a json file, then I redirected the output to a json file.  So the final command was:
`aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path "/" --recursive --with-decryption --region us-east-2 --output json > output.json`

Answer (score 3):

Using following cmd you can easily get Name and values of parameters store.

```
$ aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path "/" --recursive --query="Parameters[*].[Name, Value]" --output json>parameters.json
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$source_path=""
$source_region=""
$destination_path=""
$destination_region=""

aws_output=$(aws ssm get-parameters-by-path \
    --path "$source_path" \
    --with-decryption \
    --recursive \
    --query "Parameters[*].[Name, Type, Value]" \
    --output json \
    --region "$source_region")

echo "$aws_output" | jq -r '.[] | [.[0], .[1], .[2]] | @tsv' | while IFS=$'\t' read -r full_source_path type value; do
    full_destination_path="${full_source_path/$source_path/$destination_path}"
    if [ "$dry_run" = true ]; then
        echo "[Dry run] Copying: $full_source_path -($type)-> $full_destination_path"
    else
        echo "[Dry run] Copying: $full_source_path -($type)-> $full_destination_path"
        aws ssm put-parameter \
            --name "$full_destination_path" \
            --value "$value" \
            --type "$type" \
            --region "$destination_region"
    fi
done
```

Or full version here:
https://gist.github.com/johnymachine/15fd9d4b7c5fdf51165258962e52488d

Answer (score -1):

This Go utility might be of help: https://github.com/b-b3rn4rd/json2ssm.

Make sure to set your AWS_PROFILE pointing to a profile in `~/.aws/config` which includes the region where your parameter store is located.

To export you can run:

```
json2ssm get-json --path=/ > parameters.json
```

To import you can run:

```
json2ssm put-json --json-file=parameters.json
```

Comment: mipmip, please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.